# Threshold for fitting generalized pareto model

Tags: r, statistics, model-fitting, power-law

I need the R code for setting a threshold while fitting a generalized Pareto distribution.

Comment: What have you tried? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I've just made a R package which exactly serves this purpose, namely [gfiExtremes](https://github.com/stla/gfiExtremes) (now also  on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gfiExtremes/index.html)).

```r
remotes::install_github("stla/gfiExtremes", build_vignettes = TRUE)
```

It allows to perform inference on the quantiles for a generalized Pareto distribution model and on the parameters of the Pareto exceedance distribution, with or without assuming the exceedance threshold is known.

#### Usage

The data must be given as a numeric vector, say `x`.

```r
library(gfiExtremes)
gf <- gfigpd2(x, beta = c(0.99, 0.995, 0.999))
summary(gf) # provides estimates and confidence intervals of the beta-quantiles
thresholdEstimate(gf) # an estimate of the threshold
```

See the examples in the package documentation and the vignette for more info.